# Awk print a value in a column that corresponds to key values

Tags: loops, for-loop, awk, key-value

I want to add a column to a file depending on a key value.
I have infile_chr"N".txt (where N is a number from 1 to 22) and I need a single output file (outfile.txt) in which the first column is N.

Here there is an example of the output file:

```
1 856108 0.02625
1 870806 0.02625
1 884635 0.02625
...
22 51111340 0.02625
22 51135384 0.02625
```

But in the input files there is no column with the number N. Here the first two lines of the input file "infile_chr1.txt", where marked with ** you can find the columns I want to print:

```
**856108**  14774   908823  40  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,    ()  0.025   0.024375    **0.02625** 0.975   0.02875
**870806**  55545   921716  40  1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,    ()  0.025   0.024375    **0.02625** 0.975   0.02875
```

I tried with this code:
`for K in {1..22}; do awk '{$2="$K"; print $2,$1,$9}' infile_chr"$K".txt >> outfile.txt; done`

but the output is wrong:

```
$K 856108 0.02625
$K 870806 0.02625
$K 884635 0.02625
$K 899937 0.02625
$K 908823 0.02625
```

Can anyone help me?
Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe this `for K in {1..5};do awk -v K="$K" 'BEGIN{print K}';done` helps?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do bash looping. `awk` can do this in a single command like this:

```bash
awk 'FNR == 1 {f = FILENAME; gsub(/^infile_chr|\.txt$/, "", f)}
     {print f, $1, $9}' infile_chr* > output

cat output 

1 856108 0.02625
1 870806 0.02625
...
...
22 356102 0.08719
22 670808 0.05442
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$2="$K"; print $2,$1,$9}'
```

This is not correct way of using shell variable inside GNU `AWK`, you should use `--assign var=val` or `-v var=val` if you want to access such variable. In this particular case, fixing code would result in

```
for K in {1..22}; do awk --assign K="$K" '{$2=K; print $2,$1,$9}' infile_chr"$K".txt >> outfile.txt; done
```

but you do not need shell `for` contraption, as you might feed GNU `AWK`'s [ARGV](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html) with filenames to consume. For example if I would need to output 1st column from TAB-sheared `file1.tsv` to `file10.tsv` I could do that by

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=10;i+=1){ARGV[++ARGC]="file" i ".tsv"}}{print $1}'
```

Explanation: I use `for` loop inside AWK, in each turn I increase number of arguments (ARGC) and put name created from `file` number `.tsv` in desired place of ARGV array.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*